# Rails 3 - Custom validator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I'm trying to make a custom validator work on my app.

I have already configured my `config.autoload.paths` and it is loading fine.

The problem is with the validator itself.

*Result of `binding pry`*

```
instance variables: @attributes  @options  @with
locals: _  _dir_  _ex_  _file_  _in_  _out_  _pry_  attribute  record  value
[12] pry(#<FileCountValidator>)> value
=> [#<Attachment id: 60, description: nil, file: "cache_600_1__img_948867_5770137d84a6c79ac825886938e...", attachable_type: "Post", attachable_id: 15, created_at: "2012-03-10 14:50:54", updated_at: "2012-03-10 14:50:54">,
 #<Attachment id: 61, description: nil, file: "cache_600_1__img_948867_90f64e01b9c871ec656a884e015...", attachable_type: "Post", attachable_id: 15, created_at: "2012-03-10 14:50:54", updated_at: "2012-03-10 14:50:54">,
 #<Attachment id: 62, description: nil, file: "cache_600_1__img_948867_85eda3946c27fa90566403ac941...", attachable_type: "Post", attachable_id: 15, created_at: "2012-03-10 14:50:54", updated_at: "2012-03-10 14:50:54">,
 #<Attachment id: nil, description: nil, file: nil, attachable_type: "Post", attachable_id: 15, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>]
[13] pry(#<FileCountValidator>)> value > @with
TypeError: compared with non class/module
from /home/kleber/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:20:in `>'
[14] pry(#<FileCountValidator>)> value.size > @with
=> true
[15] pry(#<FileCountValidator>)> value.size
=> 4
[16] pry(#<FileCountValidator>)> @with
=> 3
[17] pry(#<FileCountValidator>)>
```

So, I trying to make this comparisson exactly like I did on the pry debug console.

```
def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
  #binding.pry
   record.errors.add(attribute,"#{@with} attachments per post only. #{attribute['file'].size} detected.") if value.size > @with
  end
```

But doing this, return me the error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `size' for nil:NilClass):
  lib/validators/file_count_validator.rb:11:in `validate_each'
  app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:61:in `block in update'
  app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:60:in `update'
```

Are there any way to catch the `value` before it get enters the `validate_each` method?

Comment: What does `size.inspect` & `value.inspect` show for the first validation?

Comment: @ScottJShea please, look my edit above.

Comment: The `undefined method 'size' for nil:NilClass` should be due to `attribute['file'].size`. I think you won't need to use it and use `value.size` instead as `record.errors.add(attribute,"#{@with} attachments per post only. #{value.size} detected.") if value.size > @with`

Comment: if value > @with results in `compared with non class/module` error.

Comment: I stated comparing `value.size`(not `value`) to `@with`.

Comment: I see. `value.size < @with` also returns an error. Don't know why.. it seems to be correct now. Have you saw the debug info I pasted above?

Comment: The problem was at this part of code `#{attribute['file'].size}` since `attribute['file']` isn't an Array object, the method `size` does not exist, returning `nil` error. Am I right?

Comment: yea, you called `size` on a non-permitted resource .

Comment: @prasvin Thank you for all your help and for introduce me the `pry` gem, that is really awesome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, but the value being passed seems to be correct. `value` is meant to be the value of that attribute for that record, i.e. `record.send(attribute)` should be equal to the value.

Calling `validates :attachments, :photo_count => 2` does not send 2 to the `validate_each` method as argument `value`. You could do `:photo_count => true`, which is what I generally do, or even `:photo_count => "foo"`. The `photo_count` in your `validates` statement serves to provide that the validator is to be called by passing the value(i.e. 2 or true or "foo" for stated examples) embedded in the options hash.

Here's a way **without passing a limit to the validator**.

Create a `Constants` class and define `MAX_ATTACHMENTS` constant. I usually have it at models/constants.rb.

```
class Constants
  MAX_ATTACHMENTS = 1
end
```

Then, in the validator, you could do

```
class PhotoCountValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    record.errors.add(attribute,"#{Constants::MAX_ATTACHMENTS} attachments per post only.") if record.send(attribute).size > Constants::MAX_ATTACHMENTS
  end
end
```

**Another way that passes a parameter to a validator**:

```
validates :attachments, :photo_count => 3 #desired_limit
```

Override the initialize method for PhotoCountValidator class, and initialize a class variable :

```
def initialize(options)
  @@max_objects = options[:with] # the options hash will be as {:attributes=>[:attachments], :with=>3}, where :with contains the desired limit passed
  super
end
```

Then within the `validate_each` method :

```
record.errors.add(attribute,"#{@@max_objects} attachments per post only.") if record.send(attribute).size > @@max_objects
```

Comment: But does have any way to pass the parameter as `:limit` the way I want to? anyway, doing as you said could work. I will try it.

Comment: The first option passing the limit thro a defined constant returns the following error `uninitialized constant LimitValidator::Constants`

Comment: And the second option (edit part) acting weird, for the first time, it doesn't allow me to upload 3 files even I limiting to 4 and the after tries just let me attach how many files I want, with no limitations.

Comment: Hmm..for the first error, have you created a `Constants` class and defined MAX_ATTACHMENTS in it ? For the weird behavoiur, I'll need more info. Can you paste the values of `@@max_objects`, `record`, `attribute`, `value` in `validate_each` method for both the first as well as the second time.

Comment: yes, for the first example, I have defined the MAX_ATTACHMENTS constant. and I pasted the debug result for the values that you asked me.

Comment: Where's the debug result?? Can't seem to find it. Anyways, I meant creating a Constants class in a different file. I usually have it at models/constants.rb. And see the update - I have separated the two solutions.

Comment: I noted you modified `attribute.size` to `record.send(attribute).size` and maybe now it works as expected. I will try it and back with the results.

I was not sure about where should I create a different file for storage the `Constants` that's why I created it on the same file.

Comment: I changed to `record.send(attribute).size` and it doesn't work yet. This is the debug result 


attribute size = 50130
Constants::MAX_ATTACHMENTS = 1
attribute size = 35810
Constants::MAX_ATTACHMENTS = 1
attribute size = 35810
Constants::MAX_ATTACHMENTS = 1

Comment: Hmm..so the only thing that remains to be resolved is the attribute size. Do you use some type of debugger such as `ruby-debug` or `pry`(recommended) gems? I think now you've got to help yourself as its only you who has access to your code. Then, halt the execution sequence in the first line of `validate_each` method using `binding.pry` if using pry and then try determining what actually returns you the size of your attachments.

Comment: I didn't know about this such `pry`, so I watched the railscasts about it and installed on my side, after that, I realize I was doing the validation at the wrong place! So moved the validation to the RIGHT place and debugging I'm almost there. I will paste the error I'm getting now.